# Is there a way to extract style information of documents out of tesseract?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, ocr, tesseract

I wanted to extract the style information of the text documents from tesseract.Those style information include information about the headings,subheadings,text style like bold,italic and underline.Which part of tesseract's code gives me this information ?

Answer (score 0):

`ResultIterator` class has `WordFontAttributes` method that produces the font information.

Comment: how do I get that information out of tesseract ? I wanted that boolean values for each line present in the document image.

Comment: See [APIExample](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample) & [Java example](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/HEAD/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/test/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPITest.java).